# How to set default value for radio button in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a input form I get the props and I'm mapping them for input components but for radio buttons I'm not able to set default value upon loading. Any solutions?

updateForm.jsx Now how do I select the default radio button based on employee role admin or representative?

updateForm.jsx

```
const updateForm = props => {
const { sortedEmployees } = props.location.state;

 const [updateFormData, handleUpdateForm] = useState({
    emp_name: sortedEmployees.emp_name,
    emp_phone: sortedEmployees.emp_phone,
    emp_role: sortedEmployees.emp_role
  });
  const { emp_name, emp_phone, emp_role } = updateFormData;

  const handleEmployeeForm = e => {
    handleUpdateForm({ ...updateFormData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

     <form className="w-full" onSubmit={e => handleUpdateEmployee(e)}>
        <label className="label ml-2" htmlFor="Name">
          Name
        </label>
        <input
          className="input ml-2 mb-2"
          type="text"
          name="emp_name"
          value={emp_name}
          id="Name"
          required
          placeholder="Name"
          onChange={e => handleEmployeeForm(e)}
        />
        <label className="label ml-2" htmlFor="Phone">
          Phone Number
        </label>
        <input
          className="input ml-2 mb-2"
          type="text"
          pattern="[0-9]*"
          name="emp_phone"
          value={emp_phone}
          id="Phone"
          required
          placeholder="Phone number"
          onChange={e => handleEmployeeForm(e)}
        />
        <span className="ml-2 mr-4 font-semibold">Role</span>
        <label htmlFor="admin">Admin</label>
        <input
          className="ml-2 mr-2"
          type="radio"
          name="emp_role"
          value="admin"
          id="admin"
          onChange={e => handleEmployeeForm(e)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="representative">Representative</label>
        <input
          className="ml-2 mr-2"
          type="radio"
          name="emp_role"
          value="representative"
          id="representative"
          onChange={e => handleEmployeeForm(e)}
        />
        <button type="submit" value="submit" className="button is-primary ml-2">
          Update
        </button>
      </form>
}
```

Comment: Some kind of code example is needed mate :)

Comment: What do you mean by controlled component. Can you please give some example of your code?

Comment: I apologize since I used useState hook it is not a controlled component, however I gave the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `checked` on your radiobuttton:

```
<label htmlFor="admin">Admin</label>
<input
  className="ml-2 mr-2"
  type="radio"
  name="emp_role"
  checked={emp_role === 'admin'}
  value="admin"
  id="admin"
  onChange={e => handleEmployeeForm(e)}
/>
<label htmlFor="representative">Representative</label>
<input
  className="ml-2 mr-2"
  type="radio"
  name="emp_role"
  value="representative"
  checked={emp_role === 'representative'}
  id="representative"
  onChange={e => handleEmployeeForm(e)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use state and set default value for it and then use in your radio input.

```
function Example() {
  const [gender, setGender] = useState('male');
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        checked={gender === "male"}
        type="radio"
        id="male"
        name="gender"
        value="male"
        onChange={e => setGender(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="male">Male</label>
      <br />
      <input
        checked={gender === "female"}
        type="radio"
        id="female"
        name="gender"
        value="female"
        onChange={e => setGender(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="female">Female</label>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```